# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubicomp/ubicomp/questions_check'. (Put files in SFTP server. )

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-16.04, pysftp

I am trying to put files in `sftp` server using the following code. I am using ubuntu 16.04.

```
import pysftp as sftp

def sftp_file_transfer():
    s = sftp.Connection('ip_address', username='username', password='password')
    remote_path = '/var/sftp/uploads/'
    local_path = '/home/ubicomp/ubicomp/questions_check'
    s.put(local_path, remote_path)
    s.close()
```

I have varied the path which exists. But I am getting the error. And I can not find the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubicomp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/ubicomp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/ubicomp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/ubicomp/ubicomp/import_files/views.py", line 34, in sftp_file_transfer
s.put(local_path, remote_path)
File "/home/ubicomp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 364, in put
confirm=confirm)
File "/home/ubicomp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 757, in put
file_size = os.stat(localpath).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubicomp/ubicomp/questions_check'
```

Comment: seems like the `.csv` extension is not in the path, since it ends with `ubicomp/questions_check'`...

Comment: Sorry. I am getting the error without the .csv extension. I have edited my post. And thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The remote path had to changed. And it is working just fine.

```
import pysftp as sftp

def sftp_file_transfer():
s = sftp.Connection('ip_address', username='username', password='password')
remote_path = '/uploads/questions_check.csv'
local_path = '/home/ubicomp/ubicomp/questions_check.csv'
s.put(local_path, remote_path)
s.close()
```

I had to mention a filename in the remote path with the same extension and cancel the /var/sftp part